When replacing a window screen frame does frame thickness matter by 1/16"?
I am replacing a bent window screen frame, in my home, with a thickness of 3/8".

1st frame from the left
The problem, however, is that most supply stores near me carry 5/16". Would it be a problem if I opted for 5/16" (1/16" shorter) for the window screen frame's thickness? Would this cause the screen to rattle? During heavy winds? Is a 1/16" difference really that significant?
More visualizers



The thickness of the frame might be related to the size (length and width) in order to provide sufficient strength for large frames without appearing strangely thick for small frames.   Hopefully, the supplier of these frames (or wherever you got the pictures) specifies maximum recommended lengths for each thickness?

This is frame material for fly screens, if it is too thick it will not fit into your window frame.
If you choose a size that is too thin it may rattle. but that can be mitigated by adding pieces of foam tape etc.

I didn’t think about the foam tape. I’ll install it with a 1/16” shorter thickness and see if it rattles. If so, then I will use shorter tape and update this question with the results. Thank you.

I mean, odds are that for a screen window frame you can "bend" it a little bit so it's not perfectly flat, which will solve most problems with rattling in the tracks.  If it's not already not-flat!

The screen frames I've worked with had small springs on one edge to preload the frame and prevent it from moving too much.
